# How to create and mint assets in benchmarks

Tags: benchmarking, assets, benchmark

I am building a pallet which uses assets in a loosely-coupled manner. In the pallet's `Config`, there's an associated type `Assets` with [`Inspect`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/traits/tokens/fungibles/trait.Inspect.html) and [`Transfer`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/traits/tokens/fungibles/trait.Transfer.html) bounds.

Now, when writing benchmarks, I need some way to create and mint assets. Otherwise, my pallet won't be able to perform any transfers. I know that assets pallet implements both [`Create`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/traits/tokens/fungibles/trait.Create.html) and [`Mutate`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/traits/tokens/fungibles/trait.Mutate.html) traits, but as far as I understand, I cannot use any methods from these traits in my pallet's benchmarks, as long as they're not explicitly added to the `Config`. And I don't want to do that, because it seems really bad design to add trait bounds for the sake of benchmarks only.

So, how could I create and mint assets for my benchmarks??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, there's a really simple solution to this problem. The benchmarking framework allows to introduce additional trait bounds in a `where_clause` block. So, in order to be able to create and mint assets, I just need to add the following code:

```rust
benchmarks! {
    where_clause {
        where
            T::Assets: Create<T::AssetId> + Mutate<T::AssetId>
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This could be a good use for feature flags since you have the following requirement:
Depend on a trait *only* in benchmarking.

You can see this multiple times already being used for example in the config of the `Uniques` pallet:

```rust
#[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
/// A set of helper functions for benchmarking.
type Helper: BenchmarkHelper<Self::CollectionId, Self::ItemId>;
```

The `BenchmarkHelper` trait then provides everything you need for benchmarking.

In the runtime config this can be easily configured via:

```rust
#[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
type Helper = ();
```

Answer (score 2):

One way of achieving this would be a setup similar to `pallet-xcm-benchmarks`.

[Here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/59aa955576e963942c60e3ae8f8316444b66cafb/xcm/pallet-xcm-benchmarks/src/lib.rs#L34) you can find the benchmarking pallet's `Config` that contains a `Config` of whatever pallet should be tested. This approach gives you freedom to implement any necessary helpers you might need. You can find some sample benchmarking code [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/59aa955576e963942c60e3ae8f8316444b66cafb/xcm/pallet-xcm-benchmarks/src/generic/benchmarking.rs#L53). Of course it doesn't necessarily need to be a separate pallet.

EDIT: Oliver's [answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/3955/2935) might actually be an easier solution for this kind of thing.